# PHP create file in same directory as script

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

```
$content = "some text here"; 
$fp = fopen("myText.txt","w"); 
fwrite($fp,$content); 
fclose($fp);
```

The above code creates a file in the folder where the PHP script is present. However when the script is called by Cpanel Cron then file is created in home directory.

I want file to be created in the same folder where the php script is present even if its run by cron. 
How to do that ?

Comment: You shoud use full path to the folder in PHP code

Comment: try `__DIR__ `constant to access current script directory or `basename( __FILE__)` if you are running old PHP interpreter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `__DIR__ . "/myText.txt"` as filename.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, using the [`dirname(__FILE__)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) built-in macro.

```
<?php

$content = "some text here";
$this_directory = dirname(__FILE__);
$fp = fopen($this_directory . "/myText.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, $content); 
fclose($fp);

?>
```

`__FILE__` is the full path of the currently running PHP script. `dirname()` returns the containing directory of a given file. So if your script was located at `/mysite.com/home/dir/prog.php`, `dirname(__FILE__)` would return...

```
/mysite.com/home/dir
```

Thus, the appended "./myText.txt" in the `fopen` statement. I hope this helps.